# How to get Qt working on the blackberry playbook

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-qnx

I am completely frustrated because I have been trying to install Qt on Blackberry Playbook for over a month now. I have followed every single tutorial out there (so much that every time I google Qt and playbook, all links are purple instead of blue). I have downloaded Qt-everywhere source code and tried to compile it using the flags found [here](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt4-for-Blackberry), but it tells me that it cannot install opengl, sqlite etc, so I use the `--continue` option with `./configure` and that too crashes saying that it can't find qcc.

I have noticed a Qt library directory when browsing `incudes` in the qnx IDE, in the project explorer. The thing is when i write a Qt application it can't find the headers.
So Please Help, anyone who has done this in the RECENT past . ps. i am new to cross compiling on linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Probably quite late to say, but I have created a [BlackBerry Native Plugin for Visual Studio 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b21e9d1-a54b-4d58-878f-2d53604e85b1), where you can develop apps for BlackBerry PlayBook and Qt in particular.

Simply create new project "Other Languages / BlackBerry Projects / Qt / PlayBook - Qt4 Core Application" and you are ready to go. It downloads all required libraries via NuGet during first build.

Comment: Wow, someone is actually still developing for the Playbook. And here I was getting ready to throw mine away!

Comment: someone, sometimes, but you can't call it a *market* anymore and do it is done mostly for fun